# Respecting GROUP BY Clause in a MySQL SUB-QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns some figures from a table of sales data. The table contains data for a number of different sales managers. I need to return data for the individual managers and also some calculated figures.
One of the figures I'm trying to get at involves a subquery. Getting the figures for each individual manager is fine and works well. The problem occurs when I am trying to get a figure which involves the use of a subquery. It seems that, though the outer query uses a group by clause to separate out individual salespeople, the subquery operates on the entire set.

Sample Data

```
name | Amount | Sell_at | Profit
--------------------------------
Fred | 1      | 3.99    | 0.99
Joe  | 2      | 10.50   | 5.00
Fred | 5      | 20.00   | 15.00
Joe  | 10     | 10.00   | 6.00
```

Desired result:

```
name | Total Profit | < 50% | > 50%
------------------------------------
Fred |    75.99     | 0.99  | 75.00
Joe  |    71.00     | 60    | 10
```

```
SELECT 
Account_Manager,
SUM(Profit * Amount) AS 'Total Profit'
(SELECT sum(Profit * Amount) from sales WHERE Profit * Amount / (Sell_at * Amount) < 0.5) AS '< 50%',
(SELECT sum(Profit * Amount) from sales WHERE Profit * Amount / (Sell_at * Amount) > 0.5) AS '> 50%'
FROM sales WHERE Invoice_Date = 'some date' GROUP BY Account_Manager
```

This gives me a row for each salesperson and their profit for that day, but the sub queries return figures totaled from the entire table. I could add a clause to the subquery WHERE in order to limit the result to the same date as the outer query, but ideally what I need to do really is to get the results for each individual salesperson.

Am I on the right track or is there another way I should be approaching this?

Comment: I just used the single quotes in the example so I didn't trigger anything in the Stack Overflow editor. In the actual query I use backticks and it runs fine, it's just not producing the results I'm after. Now edited.

Comment: There is no *correlation* between your sub query and outer query. You are also querying the same table for the same data multiple times - this should be sounding an alarm (Do not Repeat Yourself).

Comment: So, how do I get at the figures I'm currently getting with the subqueries without using subqueries?

Comment: Various ways eg window functions, lateral joins. Edit your question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: @Drum . . . You still have not described what results you want -- just that your subqueries do not do *something*.  What is that *something*?

Comment: Edited to add sample data and desired results

Comment: Check again your expected results for Joe.

Comment: That was just made-up data for the purposes of illustration. Not surprised if I made errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to classify the rows based on their percentile, then use window functions.  Let me assume that you want to know who is above and below average:

```
SELECT Account_Manager,
       SUM(Profit * Amount) AS Total_Profit,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(Profit * Amount) > AVG(SUM(Profit * Amount)) OVER ()
             THEN 'Above average'
             WHEN SUM(Profit * Amount) < AVG(SUM(Profit * Amount)) OVER ()
             THEN 'Below average'
             ELSE 'Average'
        END) as relative_position
FROM sales
WHERE Invoice_Date = 'some date'
GROUP BY Account_Manager;
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of Window functions until today. I'll give your solution a try.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data and desired results it appears you only need a conditional aggregate:

```
select  Name, sum(amount * profit) as TotalProfit,
    Sum(case when Profit * Amount / (Sell_at * Amount) < 0.5 then Profit * Amount end) as '<50%',
    Sum(case when Profit * Amount / (Sell_at * Amount) > 0.5 then Profit * Amount end) as '>50%'
from t
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
Profit * Amount / (Sell_at * Amount)
```

is equivalent to just:

```
Profit / Sell_at
```

Use it in a CASE expression to perform conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Account_Manager, 
       SUM(Amount * Profit) as TotalProfit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Profit / Sell_at < 0.5 THEN Profit * Amount END) `< 50%`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Profit / Sell_at > 0.5 THEN Profit * Amount END) `> 50%`
FROM Sales
WHERE Invoice_Date = 'some date'
GROUP BY Account_Manager;
```

You should also check for the case that `Profit / Sell_at` is equal to `0.5`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=084f5cb4a3b8f5bfe94e5fca9f5291c9).